# Resources String to Xaml in Win 7 phone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, resources

I Want to do something like this (but in win phone 7):

In Silverlight i can use in resources,

```
<sys:String x:Key="ResourceString">Resource String</sys:String>
```

And use it for example:

```
<TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ResourceString}"></TextBlock>
```

The question is:

How do I use a String resource in winphone 7?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this MSDN document about string resources:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637520(v=VS.92).aspx

Comment: It's another way to go. But I really want put the resource in .xaml file. 
Without resource file (.resx). 
Do you know if i have a chance?

Comment: Hey, I just tried and your example works just like you have it there. Just put those inbetween the <Application.Resources> tag in App.xaml.... or you can use an additional ResourceDictionary.. ill post an example in my next comment

Comment: put this in App.xaml, and the rest of your declarations in ResoureDictionary.xaml <Application.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionary.xaml" />
        
    </Application.Resources

Comment: I found the problem, i need put this (in the header): xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
Thank you!